# Checking radio group either empty/null

Tags: java, android

I want to check in android  that radiogroup is empty or null i.e submitted without clicking on any radio button in that group??

**Xml Code**

```
<RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/lift"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RadioButton  
                android:paddingRight="50dip"  
                android:textSize="20dp"  
                android:id="@+id/r91"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/yes" />

            <RadioButton   
                android:paddingRight="50dip"   
                android:textSize="20dp"  
                android:id="@+id/r92"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/no" />
        </RadioGroup>
```

**Activity Code**

```
RadioGroup radioGroup1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.lift);
if(radioGroup1=='NULL')
{ 
    Toast.makeText(getApplOicationContext(),"first radiogroup is null",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use below method to get checked radio button ID, if it returns -1 ,means user didn’t  selected any radio button.

```
 radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId(); // it will return unique ID of checked radio button or -1 on empty selection.
```

see the doc here >> [getCheckedRadioButtonID();](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html#getCheckedRadioButtonId%28%29)

```
 public int getCheckedRadioButtonId ()
```

> **Returns the identifier of the selected radio button in this group. Upon empty selection, the returned value is -1.**

**Related XML Attributes**
    android:checkedButton

**Returns**

```
the unique id of the selected radio button in this group
```

**Edit :-**

```
  if(radioGroup1.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1) {
    //empty selection
   } else {
     // user selected one radio button.
   }
```

Comment: I need your other help. Suppose i have list of 10 items i.e <ListView> so can you tell me how can i change background color of particular item in list after coming back from inside. Did you get my questions? After particular action i want to highlight user that you have visited this particular section.so please help me

Comment: you need to create customAdapter for this, try adding different question. it will help u get more suggestions..

Comment: I have no idea how can i put this in question form. so can you give me questions in terms of technical term for this issue??

Comment: Better you search on so or google "how to create custom adapter for list". so now u can add ur own items and add images and all in list item. 2nd question how to make one item with different color. there is a getview method in custom adapter, this method create rows for list. in this u can change background color of particular rows.
so first learn how to create custom adapter, right? then post this question of how to change colors of rows. So people will not close ur question. post the link of that question here too i wll get back to u.,